# How to allow .htaccess if you are in folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is my current .htaccess. It doesn't work when I put it in a folder (it works otherwise). It just gives Not Found page. Why is that?

Comment: Where are you putting it, if not in a folder, when it does work?

Comment: Does index.php exist in the folder you place it in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for a sub directory you need to specify the path like

```
RewriteBase /subdir/
```

in the top of your file, right after `RewriteEngine On`